# My program goes into an infinite loop whenever I run it, but only whenever I enter an invalid number then a character or string

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

In my program, I am trying to validate the users input an make sure that the only thing they can put in is a number between 1998-2019. The problem is, whenever I input a number first(and only a number), the program runs fine but if I put an invalid number then a character or string, the program goes into an infinite loop. The program also runs whenever I type in a character or string first then a number, but if I type in a character after I have typed in a number, it enters an infinite loop. Does anybody know why this is occurring or have a possible solution?

This is the code causing the problem:

```
   while (userInputYear < 1998 && userInputYear != -99 || userInputYear > 2019)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter an integer between 1998 and 2019: ";
    
        while (!(cin >> userInputYear)) 
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            cout << "\nPlease enter an integer between 1998 and 2019: ";
        }
    }
```

When I use the above code this is what is displayed:

> National Championship Inquiry
>
> Reading the input file...
>
> Enter a year between 1998 - 2019 to find the champion (press -99 to
> stop):  2019
>
> The LSU Tigers were the National Champions in 2019
>
> Enter a year between 1998 - 2019 to find the champion (press -99 to
> stop):  two thousand
>
> Please enter an integer between 1998 and 2019: Please enter an integer
> between 1998 and 2019: -99
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

This is my entire program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Champs
{
private:
    ifstream inChamps;      //input file

    int ayear[22];          //arrays
    string aname[22];

    int userInputYear = 0;              //holds value for user input


    void openFile();
    void testFile();
    void readFile();
    void validate();
    void yearName();
    void closeFile();

public:
    void driver()
    {
        openFile();
        readFile();
        yearName();
        closeFile();
    }
};

void Champs::openFile()                         //opens input file
{
    inChamps.open("NationalChampionship.txt");      
}

void Champs::readFile()
{
    if (inChamps.is_open())
    {
        cout << "National Championship Inquiry" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Reading the input file..." << endl << endl;
    }
    else
        testFile();
}

void Champs::testFile()
{
    cout << "Unable to open input file";
    exit(1);
}

void Champs::yearName()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
    {
        int year;
        inChamps >> year;
        ayear[i] = year;

        string name;
        getline(inChamps >> ws, name);
        aname[i] = name;
    }

    

    //validate input
    
    bool on = true;
    while (on == true)
    {
        cout << "Enter the year: ";
        cin >> userInputYear;
        validate();
    
        if (userInputYear == -99)
            {
                on = false;
                break;
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
        {
            
            if (userInputYear == ayear[i])
            {
                cout << "\nIn " << userInputYear << " the " << aname[i] << " won the national championship.\n\n";
            }
            
        }
    }
}

void Champs::validate()
{
    while (userInputYear < 1998 && userInputYear != -99 || userInputYear > 2019)
{
    cout << "\nPlease enter an integer between 1998 and 2019: ";

    while (!(cin >> userInputYear)) 
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        cout << "\nPlease enter an integer between 1998 and 2019: ";
    }
}

void Champs::closeFile()
{
    inChamps.close();
}

int main()
{
    Champs obj;
    obj.driver();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am still very new to c++ but I feel like this is something simple I am missing. Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Also,

Comment: Read *lines* of text, then put that text into an `std::istringstream` and attempt to extract the value you need from that string stream. That way you won't have any problems with the invalid input still being left in the input buffer of `std::cin` (which is the problem you have now).

Comment: First of all it never goes into the first while loop. Secondly when you read a character into a integer, the fail bit on cin is set. That is you can never read from the stream and it will always return, since it fails on invalid input every time. Hence the infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

In the second while loop, you are going to into the infinite loop because there are invalid characters left in the buffer. When cin encounters invalid characters it goes into an error state, when this happens you must:
1.You have to test for this error state.
2.You have to clear the error state.
3. You have to either alternatively handle the input data that generated the error state, or flush it out and reprompt the user.
Something like this would me more appropriate:

```
while (userInputYear < 1998 && userInputYear !=-99 || userInputYear > 2019)
    {
        cout << "Please enter an integer between 1998 and 2019: ";
        while(!(cin >> userInputYear)) {
          cin.clear();
          cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
          cout << "Please enter an integer between 1998 and 2019: ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: When I used that to prevent the infinite loop, I am no longer able to repeat "Please enter an integer between 1998 and 2019: ". I removed the first while loop because user3389943 informed me that it never goes through that loop. Currently I only have the while statement that you modified in validate().

Comment: The program is currently displaying:`National Championship Inquiry

Reading the input file...

Enter a year between 1998 - 2019 to find the champion (press -99 to stop):  abc

Please enter an integer between 1998 and 2019: abc'

Comment: So i used that and it was still unsuccessful. When i ran the program, "Please enter an integer between 1998 and 2019: " is repeated twice. Then i created another code: while ((!(cin >> userInputYear)) && (userInputYear < 1998) && (userInputYear != -99) || (userInputYear > 2019))
 {
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
  cout << "Please enter an integer between 1998 and 2019: ";
  cout << endl;
 }       Unfortunately when I do this, I am no longer able to use -99 to end the program.

Comment: I edited my original question so it is more clear what my program currently looks like. But I left the original code in the 'full program'.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that in my updated code, if I enter -99 twice, the program will end. I feel like the !(cin>>userInputYear) might be doing something weird but I am not exactly sure why or how to fix it.

Comment: If you use only the while loop I provided in the answer for the validate function it should work, you don't really need to check for -99 in the validate function as you do so right after in the yearName function which is where it is being called

Comment: I did use just your while loop, but when I first enter an int, then on the following cin I enter something like "yes", the program repeats "Please enter an integer..." twice. It does not crash or anything but is repeating for some reason.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, if an invalid input is entered ("yes"), then shouldn't the user be prompted again?

Comment: I will edit my original question and try to show what the current code displays.